# How to show an applet at Bonita BPM form?

Tags: java, applet, business-process-management

---

When I try to show an applet at Bonita Form through HTML Widget with Data:

```
<applet archive="jarfile-with-applet-code.jar" code="com.company.applets.MyFooApplet.class" width="400" height="500"> </applet>
```

I got this error:

```
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.applets.MyFooApplet.class
load: class com.company.applets.MyFooApplet.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.applets.MyFooApplet.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:249)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:179)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:690)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.cre
```

I already JAR file (Select Pool > Application > Dependencies > Add JAR), but still not works.

I think when I press [Run] at toolbar, the WAR generated lost dependencies.. or template generated to page dont find the applet class..

Comment: What happens when you try a direct fetch on the Jar using the URL in the browser address bar?  Does the Jar actually contain the required class (check it)?

Comment: yep, it has.. btw jar with Applet class contains dependencies jar files too. i don't know how i can access applet class through asp file through Bonita templates

Answer (score 2):

I used an applet in Bonita to embed ms office documents. Ive made it to work by using default package in the applet class. Then add your applet jar and dependencies in your proccess by selecting the pool -> Application  -> Resources -> Add File, of course it better if you first signed the applet jars. Note that (Select Pool > Application > Dependencies > Add JAR) approach wont work cause these are the runtime core process libraries, the applet is an standalone application independent from the BOS core. I Hope this helps